# How can I push to Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, anaconda

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku. After I execute `git push heroku master --force`, I get the error

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.14".
```

I´ve already installed anaconda

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-client"
```

but nothing happens.[image]

Comment: Do you check which `conda` are you using? I suggest trying `which conda` and double-check the result with your current environment. Maybe you've installed anaconda-client, but not in the same environment that you're working.

Comment: Anaconda-client version in my environment is 1.6.14

Answer (score 0):

Heroku installs Python packages from PyPI and the latest `anaconda-client` on PyPI is `1.2.2`:

https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/#history

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369348/2011147) for a (not so simple) workaround.

Comment: I have Anaconda-client 1.6.14 version in my environment. So, I have to unistall this and install the new one. But, how can I uninstall this?